# Converting Large MS Access Database to CSV

Tags: ms-access, export-to-csv

I am getting data from someone to analyze and what they have given me are very large Access files. I want to convert them to CSV. Opening up the files in MS Access 2013 and exporting as CSV has been easy enough; however, one MDB file is 2GB and I can't even open it in Access.

All of the MDB files only have one table, so that makes my life easier. Is there a way to convert a 2 GB MDB file to CSV, perhaps using a script/program or something? If it helps, I'm using a Windows machine.

Thanks.

Comment: Try creating a blank access database and then importing the large table from the 2GB database. (during the import then dead records and deleted records will not be imported - you likely wind up with a MUCH smaller database with the same table data.

Answer (score 1):

A2013 may try to convert it when opening it.

Try creating a new database and create a link in this to the table in the 2 GB database file.

Or try using Access 2003 or Visual Studio (the Community edition is free), or attach is a linked database in SQL Server (the Express edition is free).